# Click button not allowing to add click count

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I am currently making a voting app that when the button is clicked it will changed from the name "Kiwi" to the amount of clicks the button has had when the toggle button is clicked. When the toggle button is clicked again it reverts back to the name of the button and then clicked again shows the number of clicks. My problem is that when I want to click the button that is showing to increase the click count it won't add another click it will only do so if the button is showing the name not the count. Anyone know if I have done something wrong, here is my code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/buzzyBeeImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/buzzybeeimage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.165"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/buzzybee" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gumbootsImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gumbootsimage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.807"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/gumboots" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/kiwiImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/kiwiimage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.133"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.557"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/kiwi" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tikiImg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/tikiimage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.855"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.557"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/tiki" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buzzyBeeBt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/buzzy_bee"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.196"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.364" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gumbootsBt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/gumboots"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.797"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.364" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/kiwiBt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/kiwi"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.188"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tikiBt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tiki"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.767"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.751" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toggleCounterBt"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:text="@string/toggle_counters"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.482"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.956" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leaderTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/current_leader"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.853" />







public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Creates Hash map
private static HashMap<String, Integer> votes = new HashMap<>();

private int kiwiCounter = 0;
private int tikiCounter = 0;
private int gumbootsCounter = 0;
private int buzzyBeeCounter = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Sets references to widgets
    final Button btKiwi = findViewById(R.id.kiwiBt);
    final Button bttiki = findViewById(R.id.tikiBt);
    final Button btGumboots = findViewById(R.id.gumbootsBt);
    final Button btBuzzyBee = findViewById(R.id.buzzyBeeBt);
    final Button btToggleCounter = findViewById(R.id.toggleCounterBt);
    final TextView txtLeader = findViewById(R.id.leaderTextView);
    btToggleCounter.setTag(1);

    // Populating
    votes.put("Kiwi",0);
    votes.put("Tiki",0);
    votes.put("Gumboots",0);
    votes.put("Buzzy Bee",0);



    btKiwi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            kiwiCounter++;

            votes.put("Kiwi", votes.get("Kiwi") + 1);
            String winnerCupcake = "";
            Integer winnerVotes = 0;

            if (votes.get("Kiwi") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Kiwi");
                winnerCupcake = "Kiwi";
            }
            if (votes.get("Tiki") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Tiki");
                winnerCupcake = "Tiki";
            }
            if (votes.get("Gumboots") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Gumboots");
                winnerCupcake = "Gumboots";
            }
            if (votes.get("Buzzy Bee") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Buzzy Bee");
                winnerCupcake = "Buzzy Bee";

            }
            txtLeader.setText("Current Leader: " + winnerCupcake);
        }

    });

    bttiki.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){

            tikiCounter++;

            String winnerCupcake = "";
            Integer winnerVotes = 0;

            votes.put("Tiki", votes.get("Tiki")+1);

            if (votes.get("Kiwi") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Kiwi");
                winnerCupcake = "Kiwi";
            }
            if (votes.get("Tiki") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Tiki");
                winnerCupcake = "Tiki";
            }
            if (votes.get("Gumboots") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Gumboots");
                winnerCupcake = "Gumboots";
            }
            if (votes.get("Buzzy Bee") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Buzzy Bee");
                winnerCupcake = "Buzzy Bee";

            }
            txtLeader.setText("Current Leader: " + winnerCupcake);

        }

    });

    btGumboots.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){

            gumbootsCounter++;

            String winnerCupcake = "";
            Integer winnerVotes = 0;

            votes.put("Gumboots", votes.get("Gumboots")+1);

            if (votes.get("Kiwi") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Kiwi");
                winnerCupcake = "Kiwi";
            }
            if (votes.get("Tiki") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Tiki");
                winnerCupcake = "Tiki";
            }
            if (votes.get("Gumboots") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Gumboots");
                winnerCupcake = "Gumboots";
            }
            if (votes.get("Buzzy Bee") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Buzzy Bee");
                winnerCupcake = "Buzzy Bee";

            }
            txtLeader.setText("Current Leader: " + winnerCupcake);
        }
    });

    btBuzzyBee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){

            buzzyBeeCounter++;

            String winnerCupcake = "";
            Integer winnerVotes = 0;

            votes.put("Buzzy Bee", votes.get("Buzzy Bee")+1);

            if (votes.get("Kiwi") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Kiwi");
                winnerCupcake = "Kiwi";
            }
            if (votes.get("Tiki") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Tiki");
                winnerCupcake = "Tiki";
            }
            if (votes.get("Gumboots") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Gumboots");
                winnerCupcake = "Gumboots";
            }
            if (votes.get("Buzzy Bee") > winnerVotes){
                winnerVotes = votes.get("Buzzy Bee");
                winnerCupcake = "Buzzy Bee";

            }
            txtLeader.setText("Current Leader: " + winnerCupcake);

        }
    });

    btToggleCounter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int status = (Integer)v.getTag();
            if(status== 1){
                btKiwi.setText(Integer.toString(kiwiCounter));
                bttiki.setText(Integer.toString(tikiCounter));
                btGumboots.setText(Integer.toString(gumbootsCounter));
                btBuzzyBee.setText(Integer.toString(buzzyBeeCounter));

                v.setTag(0);
            }
            else {
                btKiwi.setText("Kiwi");
                bttiki.setText("Tiki");
                btGumboots.setText("Gumboots");
                btBuzzyBee.setText("Buzzy Bee");

                v.setTag(1);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
btKiwi.setText(String.valueOf(kiwiCounter));
bttiki.setText(String.valueOf(tikiCounter));
btGumboots.setText(String.valueOf(gumbootsCounter));
btBuzzyBee.setText(String.valueOf(buzzyBeeCounter));
```

Comment: Yes I tried that but still doesn't help with when I click the button  when it is showing the click counts to add another count it won't add it to the click count, will only do this if it is showing the text